# How do I fix the extra word coming in the end?

Tags: python, string, list, loops, exception

I am writing a code for adding strings alternatively. It is like this:
If we have 2 strings:

```
a = "abcd"
b = "efgh"
```

When we add them the solution should be "aebfcgdh". If there is any extra part of string in any variable it should be added in the end. Now moving onto my code. Here it is:

```
words1 = "rmiiab"
words2 = "eanna"
if len(words1) > len(words2):
    maxLength = len(words1)
elif len(words1) == len(words2):
    maxLength = len(words1)
else:
    maxLength = len(words2)
result = []
extras = []
for i in range(0, maxLength):
    try:
        result.append(words1[i])
        result.append(words2[i])
    except IndexError:
        remainingWords = maxLength - i
        if len(words1) > len(words2):
            extras.append(words1[-remainingWords])
        else:
            extras.append(words2[-remainingWords])
for word in extras:
    result.append(word)
for letter in result:
    print(letter, end="")
```

It is working completely fine but for one test case that is when the length of first string is greater than the length of string 2. In that case my code adds the last letter of extra words twice. I am unable to find the error. May someone help me. For the below code the output is:
**remaininaabb** when it should be **remaininaab** instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are indexing words1 first and words2 second in the *same try statement*. In this case the assignment is being completed correctly, but then failing on the second append statement and appending the last letter of the first array again. You can fix this by creating separate try statements for each append or calculating an exact number of iterations for each beforehand and avoiding the whole try/catch idea.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, it worked. What I did was not add the append for word 1 in except block because I don't know how but it was adding automatically so I left it and only added the extra part of second string in except and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The code after `except` in executed multiple times if your strings are uneven, because it doesn't break `for` loop.

```
try:
    result.append(words1[i])
    result.append(words2[i])
```

In this part the first `append` does not cause `IndexError`, therefore is executed and the letter is added even if the second `append` throws `IndexError`.

You should add `break` somewhere in `except` clause to stop looping.

Comment: Well, it worked. What I did was not add the append for word 1 in except block because I don't know how but it was adding automatically so I left it and only added the extra part of second string in except and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` the two words, find the length of the shortest word and add anything longer to the collector.

```py
words1 = "rmiiab"
words2 = "eanna"

collector = ""
for a, b in zip(words1, words2): collector += a + b
min_len = min(map(len, (words1, words2)))
collector += words1[min_len:] + words2[min_len:]

print(collector) #remaininaab
```

Comment: You don't need `min_len`: `collector += words1[len(words2):] + words2[len(words1):]` One of the summands will be empty either way.

Comment: Well, it worked. What I did was not add the append for word 1 in except block because I don't know how but it was adding automatically so I left it and only added the extra part of second string in except and it worked.

Comment: Anyways, I liked this new zip thing. I didn't know about it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library way of doing this uses `itertools.zip_longest` which works like the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) but allows for iterables of varying sizes:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

words1 = "rmiiab"
words2 = "eanna"

"".join(chain(*zip_longest(words1, words2, fillvalue="")))
# 'remaininaab'
```

`fillvalue` is used to pad the shorter iterables.

#### Docs:

- [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)
- [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

Comment: Use `itertools.chain` instead of two calls to `"".join` and `map`: `''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(...)))`.

Comment: (`chain.from_iterable` essentially "flattens" the sequence of tuples yielded by `zip_longest`.)

Comment: @chepner `chain(*...)` seems enough to me since there is little point in lazy evaluation when you are going to consume all the iterables anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it's mostly a personal preference to stay lazy as long as possible.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation for this? I have never heard of anything like this.

Comment: Which part haven't you heard of? Over the course of Python journey you will find plenty useful tools in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/).

Comment: @chepner One more thought: some of my old benchmarks showed that `str.join` itself worked significantly faster with a list (comprehension) than a generator expression. Because of the immutability of strings, the c-implementation of join would make a list first anyway to know the length of the final string. The dedicated comprehension was so highly C-optimized that it was faster than the consumption of the very general purpose generator expression which had to essentially repeatedly call `next` in a Python context. In some instances, the very nice concept of laziness comes at a cost.